# how to make a circle changes its color for every second?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I recently making a stoplight program (gui) and i can't figure it out which is wrong I dont know how to include the QTimer or any function for delay to make the color change and i tried the show function ended up getting two programs i really don't know how to fix my code yet can you please help me?

```
import PyQt5, sys, time,os
from os import system,name
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import QPoint,QTimerEvent,QTimer,Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget,QApplication,QMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter
class Stoplight(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self,parent = None):
        QWidget.__init__(self,parent)
        self.setWindowTitle("Stoplight")
        self.setGeometry(500,500,250,510)
    def paintEvent(self,event):
        radx = 50
        rady = 50
        center = QPoint(125,125)
        p = QPainter()
        p.begin(self)
        p.setBrush(Qt.white)
        p.drawRect(event.rect())
        p.end()

        p1 = QPainter()
        p1.begin(self)
        p1.setBrush(Qt.red)
        p1.setPen(Qt.black)
        p1.drawEllipse(center,radx,rady)
        p1.end()
class Stoplight1(Stoplight):
    def __init__(self,parent = None):
        QWidget.__init__(self,parent)
        self.setWindowTitle("Stoplight")
        self.setGeometry(500,500,250,510)
    def paintEvent(self,event):
        radx = 50
        rady = 50
        center = QPoint(125,125)
        p = QPainter()
        p.begin(self)
        p.setBrush(Qt.white)
        p.drawRect(event.rect())
        p.end()

        p1 = QPainter()
        p1.begin(self)
        p1.setBrush(Qt.green)
        p1.setPen(Qt.black)
        p1.drawEllipse(center,radx,rady)
        p1.end()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    application = QApplication(sys.argv)
    stoplight1 = Stoplight()
    stoplight2 = Stoplight1()
    time.sleep(1)
    stoplight1.show()
    time.sleep(1)
    stoplight2.show()
sys.exit(application.exec_())
```

Comment: Why do you want two windows appearing? Currently you are just opening two stoplight guis after a fixed delay. Do you want a change the colors inside one gui-window?

Comment: i needed to make it in just one gui-window that changes its colors from red, green and yellow for 3 circles

Comment: i just tried it btw i can't figure it out how to reset colors so i tried the show function im  sorry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although the response of [@f.wue](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9212441/f-wue)  works apparently is not correct since you should not use `time.sleep()` in the GUI thread since it freezes the application, for example try to resize the window while running the `time.sleep()`.

Instead you should use a `QTimer` as you say, that timer must connect to a function that changes the color and call the `update()` method that indirectly invokes the `paintEvent()`event. Since you want colors to change colors cyclically, you must create a cyclic iterator.

```
from itertools import cycle
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class TrafficLight(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self,parent = None):
        super(TrafficLight, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle("TrafficLight ")
        self.traffic_light_colors = cycle([
            QtGui.QColor('red'),
            QtGui.QColor('yellow'),
            QtGui.QColor('green')
        ])
        self._current_color = next(self.traffic_light_colors)
        timer = QtCore.QTimer(
            self, 
            interval=2000, 
            timeout=self.change_color
        )
        timer.start()
        self.resize(200, 400)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def change_color(self):
        self._current_color = next(self.traffic_light_colors)
        self.update()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        p = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        p.setBrush(self._current_color)
        p.setPen(QtCore.Qt.black)
        p.drawEllipse(self.rect().center(), 50, 50)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = TrafficLight()
    w.show() 
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: excuse me sir how do i put the different intervals in the colors for example 10 seconds for red then 5 for yellow and 10 for green?

Comment: @JansenLloydMacabangun If the intervals are different the logic becomes more complex, in a few moments I will update my answer.

Comment: sir i don't think you needed to update it i just figured it out a few mins ago thank you sir. i used another variable to handle the different time delays i initiate x = 0 then use if -else statement which i can change the values of the time delays thank you so much sir my gui is not lagging now,

Comment: btw sir @QtCore.pyqtSlot() what is the use of this function ?

Comment: @JansenLloydMacabangun read http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/signals_slots.html#the-pyqtslot-decorator

Comment: sir is there a book or site where i can read the functions inside the module of pyqt5?

Comment: @JansenLloydMacabangun Read the docs of Qt, there explain what each class and its methods are for.

Answer (score 0):

This would be a hint in accomplishing it. You need to define some functions or objects to handle the different locations of the cycles. Furthermore use the function `self.update()`to call the `paintEvent` and `application.processEvents()` to make the changes visible in the gui. You can use the code in the execution part and generate a more sophisticated function out of it.

**EDIT:** Try this approach with a dictionary, as it contains less code.

```
import PyQt5, sys, time,os
from os import system,name
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import QPoint,QTimerEvent,QTimer,Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget,QApplication,QMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter
class Stoplight(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self,parent = None):
        QWidget.__init__(self,parent)
        self.setWindowTitle("Stoplight")
        self.setGeometry(500,500,250,510)
        self.radx = 50
        self.rady = 50
        self.traffic_light_dic = {"red":{"QColor":Qt.red,
                                         "center":QPoint(125,125)},
                                  "yellow": {"QColor": Qt.yellow,
                                          "center": QPoint(125, 250)},
                                  "green": {"QColor": Qt.green,
                                          "center": QPoint(125, 375)},
                                  }
    def switch_to_color(self, color):
        self.center = self.traffic_light_dic[color]["center"]
        self.color = self.traffic_light_dic[color]["QColor"]
        self.update()
    def paintEvent(self, event):
        p = QPainter()
        p.begin(self)
        p.setBrush(self.color)
        p.setPen(Qt.black)
        p.drawEllipse(self.center, self.radx,self.rady)
        p.end()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application = QApplication(sys.argv)
    stoplight1 = Stoplight()
    stoplight1.show()
    time.sleep(2)
    stoplight1.switch_to_color("red")
    application.processEvents()
    time.sleep(2)
    stoplight1.switch_to_color("yellow")
    application.processEvents()
    time.sleep(2)
    stoplight1.switch_to_color("green")
    application.processEvents()
    sys.exit(application.exec_())
```